# Is there a way to get Location navigation marker on Scene

Tags: esri, arcgis-runtime

HI i am trying to build a location based AR app, which uses scenes, the map in arcgis has the facility to use `mapview.locationdisplay.autopanmode....` to position the device marker on the map is there something similar to scene too?

I tried initializing a Graphics Overlay and updating it every time the location changes but that seems to slow down the app, is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

We don’t have Location Display on scenes yet, but you should be able to do this using a graphics overlay and graphics and hooking into the device’s location yourself. I’m curious how it slows the application down (it shouldn’t).